# Mouse cursor changes size when new process starts

Tags: mouse, kde

In KDE, you may already change the mouse size in setting (maybe bigger size for better vision or smaller size for more comfort).

When new process starts, mouse change its size (usually become smaller) which is annoying.

Comment: I fixed this problem today in Ubuntu 14.04 so hope it can be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit ~/.kde/share/config/startupconfig

```
sudo gedit ~/.kde/share/config/startupconfig
```

and add the following line:

```
kcminputrc_mouse_cursorsize="20"
```

Now save the file and everything is hopefully fine.

[source](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=226264)